# Email button collecting information

Tags: forms, button, html-email, user-data

I'm dealing with a problem. I need to create a button in an email that saves the email of the person who clicked on it and redirects them to the created page. On the created page, there will be a form that the user can fill out and at the bottom of the page there will be a "Submit" button that will write into an excel spreadsheet his data that he entered in the form and on the same row in the excel, the saved email that was saved in the button he clicked in the email.

Can this be programmed and if so how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To answer your question yes this can be done but this is not a coding platform. May I suggest you take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of this site and check out the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to read on what sort of questions can be asked and the topics. We are here to help, if you have tried anything then ask specific questions accompanied by the code you have tried and someone can have a look and help you out.